# Breakpoint "skipped" when debugging async code

Tags: c#, debugging, async-await

I have some code that is returning the following exception ...

`Object reference not set to an instance of an object`

I am trying to delve in further to get to the cause, but when I set a break-point after the calling code the break-point seems to get passed by ..

```
PaymentProcessor pp = new PaymentProcessor();
List<string> results = await pp.ProcessPayment();
foreach (string result in results)  // Break-point set here
{
   ...
}
```

I wanted to see if the result of the method call returned any `results`. I think it has to do with the method making use of `async` `await`. If the break-point is being skipped because of the async method how do I stop it? I use the `async` code to free up the UI thread.

More details ....

The code where the exception bubbles up is ..

```
var paymentTask = GetPaymentUpdates();
paymentTask.Wait(); // Object not set exception occurs here.
```

Comment: Assume method is decorated with `async`? (Any way you can break this down into a single unit and confirm it still doesn't work?)

Comment: Correct .. `public async Task<List<string>> ProcessPayment()`

Comment: Is it being skipped because the `ProcessPayment` method is throwing the exception?

Comment: Side note: Methods following TAP will be better named with suffix `Async`. In this case `ProcessPaymentAsync` will be the better name which follows this guideline.

Comment: Also, look at your stack trace when you get the NullReferenceException, it should guide to you the exact location of the error.

Comment: @Joe Koemer - You are correct. It was throwing the exception inside `ProcessPayment()`;

Comment: If the exception is occurring during the asynchronous `ProcessPayment()` operation, then naturally the code won't hit the breakpoint after the `await` of that operation. That's how exceptions work, async or not.

Comment: @Joe Koemer - Put your comment in as an answer and I will mark it as the answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That code would be skipped is if the exception was being thrown in the `ProcessPayment` method and thus it never reaches that code.